# Dropdownlist não está passando o valor na varável

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer uma validação em javascript, mas não estou nem mesmo conseguindo passar o que tem dentro de uma DROPDOWNLIST para a variável para fazer a comparação...
O NomeProjetoFilho recebe perfeitamente o que tem dentro da variável, creio que por ser um TextBox.
Já o NomeProjetoPai não recebe, é um Dropdownlist...

Segue os códigos abaixo:

```
function validacaoCadastrarOS() {
    var NomeProjetoPai = document.getElementById("ProjetoId").value;
    var NomeProjetoFilho = document.getElementById("ProjetoNome").value;
    alert(NomeProjetoPai);
    alert(NomeProjetoFilho);
    if (NomeProjetoPai === NomeProjetoFilho) {
        alert("Nome da atividade não pode ser igual ao nome do Projeto");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML dessa dropdown? assim como está a pergunta está incompleta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi com JQUERY, agora ele consegue pegar o que está dentro do Dropdownlist...

```
var NomeProjetoPai = $("#ProjetoId :selected").text();
```